# How do you run the Tornado web server locally?

Tags: python, tornado

Is it possible to run Tornado such that it listens to a local port (e.g. localhost:8000). I can't seem to find any documentation explaining how to do this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add an address argument to Application.listen() or HTTPServer.listen().

It's documented [here (Application.listen)](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html) and [here (TCPServer.listen)](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/tcpserver.html).

For example:

```
application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/blah', BlahHandler),
    ], **settings)

# Create an HTTP server listening on localhost, port 8080.
http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
http_server.listen(8080, address='127.0.0.1')
```

Answer (score 2):

In the documetaion they mention to run on the specific port like

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8000)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

You will get more help from http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/overview.html and http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Once you've defined an application (like in the other answers) in a file (for example server.py), you simply save and run that file.

`python server.py`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to daemonize tornado - use supervisord. If you want to access tornado on address like `http://mylocal.dev/` - you should look at nginx and use it like reverse proxy. And on specific port it can be binded like in Lafada's answer.